# TypeError: generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json'

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in main
    output_call = output.generator(json_text)
TypeError: generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json'
```

My code:

```
class TOTALTIME:
    def generator(self, json):
        self._json = json
        print('{} minutes'.format(int(self._json['route']['time']/60)))
```

My for loop is iterating through a list of classes that I made through a dictionary.

```
for output in output_list:
    output_call = output.generator(json_text)
    print(output_call)
```

Here's the function that creates the classes:

```
def list_of_outputs(n_outputs: int) -> 'values':
    d = {}
    e = {'STEPS': output_classes.STEPS,
     'LATLONG': output_classes.LATLONG,
     'TOTALTIME': output_classes.TOTALTIME,
     'TOTALDISTANCE': output_classes.TOTALDISTANCE,
     'ELEVATION': output_classes.ELEVATION }

    for output in range(n_outputs):
        add_output = input()
        if add_output in e.keys():
            d.update(e)
    return d.values()
```

Comment: `output` appears to be the *class*, not an instance of the class.

Comment: Is `output_list` made up of `TOTALTIME`'s or `TOTALTIME()`'s?

Comment: My output_list is made up of TOTALTIME and such. It would give me an error if my dictionary went like { 'key': TOTALTIME() }

Answer (score 1):

You are calling *unbound functions*, not a bound method. You need to create *instances* to for the functions on a class to bind to something and provide the `self` argument.

In other words, your `output_list` contains `TOTALTIME` entries, not `TOTALTIME()` entries:

```
>>> class TOTALTIME:
...     def generator(self, json):
...         self._json = json
...         print('{} minutes'.format(int(self._json['route']['time']/60)))
...
>>> TOTALTIME.generator({'route': {'time': 360}})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'json'
>>> TOTALTIME().generator({'route': {'time': 360}})
6 minutes
```

Note the `()` call to create an instance.